# Ambiguity between Decimal and Float point numbers in python?

Tags: python, django

I have a value stored in a field as type `DecimalField` . When I print it, the value I get is
`>>> sr.to_value
Decimal('9.99')`
Now when I compare it to a float number
`>>> sr.to_value < 9.99
True`
Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely due to floating point inaccuracies, take a look at the docs here for a proper explanation:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Example:

```
>>> .1 + .1 + .1 == .3
False
```